# Sklearn Wont do Regression on Continuous Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Having an issue with sklearn where my regressor is not fitting using continuous labels.
Here is my code:

```
train_X = df_train_trimmed.loc[:, ~df_train_trimmed.columns.isin(['log_icu_days'])]
train_y = list(df_train_trimmed["log_icu_days"].astype(np.float32))
rfr = Pipeline(
    [
        ("preprocessor", regressor_preprocessor),
        (
            "regressor",
            RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1200, max_depth=30, criterion="squared_error", random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
        ),
    ]
)
rfr.fit(
    train_X, train_y
)
```

The error is this (minus the very long callback)

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in unique_labels(*ys)
    105     _unique_labels = _FN_UNIQUE_LABELS.get(label_type, None)
    106     if not _unique_labels:
--> 107         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
    108 
    109     if is_array_api:

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 2.19833517, -4.60517025, -4.60517025, ..., -4.60517025, -4.60517025, -4.60517025]),)
```

I have looked through the other questions, and this mostly comes up when people attempt to fit a classifier to real valued data, but here I am using a regressor, so I am not sure why this is occuring. Here is a small sample of my train_y data:

```
[2.1983350716202463,
 -4.605170185988091,
 -4.605170185988091,
 0.009950330853168092,
 0.009950330853168092,
 -4.605170185988091,
 -4.605170185988091,
...
```

This error persists no matter what regressor I use. Also, this outcome measure is a log transformation of a non-negative vector (icu length of stay in days) where I added a small value to make 0 values not be negative infinity. Every regressor I used worked fine on the non-transformed, non-negative integer outcome vector.

Update:
I tried to cast all the y data to integers, and the regression worked perfectly, but when I let them be floats, this error comes back up.

Update 2:
I tried fitting an intercept only model with no predictors. The model which used the pipeline had the error, while the model which did not use the pipeline did not have an error. This is an issue with the data pipeline. For reference, here is how I am setting up my Pipeline object:

```
categorical_features = [
    "sex", "approach", "preop_pft"
]
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("encoder", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse_output=False)),
        ("selector", SelectPercentile(chi2, percentile=50)),
    ]
)

numeric_features = list(set(df_train_trimmed.columns) - set(categorical_features) - {'icu_days', 'log_icu_days'})
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())]
)


regressor_preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
    
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
)
```

Update 3:
Here is some sample data that I exported with pd.to_csv()

,caseid,anestart,aneend,icu_days,age,sex,weight,bmi,asa,emop,approach,preop_htn,preop_dm,preop_pft,intraop_ebl,intraop_rbc,log_icu_days
3411,6246,-365,22735.0,9,8,F,31.7,15.4,3.0,0,Open,0,0,Normal,250.0,0,2.1983350716202463
3243,5959,-1602,4698.0,0,54,F,52.6,22.8,2.0,0,Videoscopic,0,1,Normal,,0,-4.605170185988091
1948,3565,-640,14900.0,0,27,F,51.8,21.5,2.0,0,Robotic,0,0,Normal,50.0,0,-4.605170185988091
2782,5118,-1144,11156.0,1,78,M,59.4,21.5,3.0,0,Open,0,0,Normal,,0,0.009950330853168092
1778,3258,-396,17904.0,1,73,F,49.5,23.7,,1,Open,0,0,Normal,1200.0,3,0.009950330853168092
982,1802,-326,13174.0,0,32,M,65.2,22.5,2.0,0,Open,0,0,Normal,300.0,0,-4.605170185988091

Update 4:
By removing the "selector" from the categorical portion of the preprocessor, the function now runs. I have no idea why this caused an error though...

Comment: What are your `pandas` and `sklearn` versions?

Comment: My pandas is 1.5.3 and my sklearn is 1.2.2

Comment: There is no column `log_icu_days` in your sample data

Comment: Just added it, I exported the training X data only on accident.

Comment: Where is your regressor preprocessor object? I cannot duplicate this error without all parts of the code.

Comment: Its near the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Like is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215510/valueerror-unknown-label-type-array-while-using-decision-tree-classifier-and-u), try using a `numpy nd.array` of type `float32` instead.

```
import numpy as np

train_X = df_train_trimmed.loc[:, ~df_train_trimmed.columns.isin(['log_icu_days'])]
train_y = np.array(df_train_trimmed["log_icu_days"]).astype(np.float32)

rfr = Pipeline(
    [
        ("preprocessor", regressor_preprocessor),
        (
            "regressor",
            RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1200, max_depth=30, criterion="squared_error", random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
        ),
    ]
)

rfr.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I got the same error. It works for np.int32 but not float32.

Comment: Can you post some sample data so I can reproduce the problem on my end @RyanFolks?

Comment: There is now some sample data in csv format at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Just got it to work. I removed the "selector" from my preprocessor. Any ideas as to why this caused an error?